# Determining if two spans are equal

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W = span\left\{(1, 4, 5) \right\} $ and $R = span\left\{(2, 2, 4), (0, 2, 2)\right\}$ be linear subspaces.

I want to check if these spans are equal, i.e. if $W = R$. To do this we have to prove two inclusions. I showed $W \subset R$ as follows. Let $w \in W$. Then $w = \lambda (1, 4, 5) = (\lambda, 4 \lambda, 5 \lambda)$ for some scalar $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. If $w \in R$ also, then we must have \begin{align*} (\lambda, 4 \lambda, 5 \lambda) &= c(2, 2, 4) + d(0, 2, 2) \\ & = (2c, 2c + 2d, 4c + 2d) \end{align*} for some scalars $c, d \in \mathbb{R}$. This led me to the system \begin{align*} \begin{cases} \lambda &= 2c \\ 4 \lambda &= 2c + 2d \\ 5 \lambda &= 4c + 2d \end{cases} \end{align*} Subtracting first equation from second gave me $(3 / 2 )\lambda = d$. Then substituting in the last gives $(1 / 2) \lambda = c$. Hence it follows that there indeed exist such scalars $c, d$, so that $W \subset R$.

Now should I just apply the same reasoning to determine if $R \subset W$ ? If we let $r \in R$, then $r = \lambda (2, 2, 4) + \mu (0, 2, 2)$. For $r \in W$ we must have \begin{align*} (2 \lambda, 2 \lambda + 2 \mu, 4 \lambda + 2 \mu) = (a, 4a, 5a) \end{align*} for some scalar $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Should I now try to solve for $a$ then?

Comment: Alternatively, a really easy way of showing that these two spans are not equal is noting the dimension of the linear subspaces. Obviously $dim(W)=1$. You can show that $dim(R)=2$ by noticing the two vectors that make up $R$ are linearly independent. Therefore, $W$ defines a line, while $R$ defines a plane; they are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

You could *try* to solve that equation for $a$, but let's try to inject some intuition here. Is it likely that the span of one vector will be equal to the span of two? Probably not - in fact, the span of two vectors will be two dimensional unless the two vectors are parallel. This isn't the case, so really we should be looking for a vector in $R$ that isn't in $W$.

But that's easy - $(0,2,2)$ can't possibly be in $W$. Why not? Well, suppose $(0,2,2)=\lambda (1,4,5)$ for some $\lambda$. Then $\lambda=0$ from the first co-ordinates. But $2 \ne 0$ (comparing the second co-ordinates). So $R \ne W$.